# R: closure which returns a different permutation when called

Tags: r, functional-programming, closures

I am looking for a closure which takes as an input, a vector of integers `x`, and returns a function which returns a different permutation of `x` each time it is called. I imagine the code looking something like this:

```
R> perm_factory <- all_perms(1:2)

R> perm_factory()
[1] 1 2
R> perm_factory()
[1] 2 1
R> perm_factory()
NULL
```

Cheers for any help :)

**EDIT:** I should have said, I am not looking for a trivial solution such as:

```
require(gtools)

all_perms <- function(x) {
  len_x <- length(x)

  perms <- permutations(len_x, len_x, x)
  len_perms <- nrow(perms)

  i <- 0

  function() {
    i <<- i + 1
    if (i > len_perms) NULL
    else perms[i, ]
  }
}
```

but rather, *a solution that will allow me to deal with permutations of an arbitrary size* (or at least a large size).

For example, in python there is the `itertools` module:

```
import itertools

perms = itertools.permutations(range(1, 1000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(gtools)
permutations(3,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
permutations(2,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
```

Next time try `??permutation` and look at doc, ok?

--edit--
Here you go:

```
sub <- function(n, r=n, v=1:n) {
    if (r == 1) 
        matrix(v, n, 1)
    else if (n == 1) 
        matrix(v, 1, r)
    else {
        X <- NULL
        for (i in 1:n) 
            X <- rbind(X,cbind(v[i], sub(n - 1, r - 1, v[-i])))
        X <- X
    }

}

all_perm <- function(n){
    X <<- sub(n)
    whichPerm <<- 0
    nextPerm <-function(){
        whichPerm <<- whichPerm+1
        if(whichPerm<=nrow(X)){
            return(X[whichPerm,])
        }else{
            return(NULL)
        }
    }
    return(nextPerm)
}
nextPerm <- all_perm(5)
nextPerm()
```

And this works like you want:

```
nextPerm <- all_perm(5)
nextPerm()
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
nextPerm()
## [1] 1 2 3 5 4
nextPerm()
## [1] 1 2 4 3 5
nextPerm()
## [1] 1 2 4 5 3
```

--edit--
A few minutes of googleing and here's what i've found:

```
require(iterpc)    
I <- iterpc(5,ordered=TRUE)
getnext(I)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
getnext(I)
## [1] 1 2 3 5 4
getnext(I)
## [1] 1 2 4 3 5
getnext(I)
## [1] 1 2 4 5 3
getnext(I)
## [1] 1 2 5 3 4
```

Comment: A call to `permutations` returns a matrix - this is not what I want e.g. `permutations(1e10, 1e10)`is going to give you a memory error. This is why I was asking for a closure which returns a different permutation per call. So next time, look at the question, ok? ;)

Comment: So next time be more specific in your question, ok? :) You should write what you have tried so far. :)

Comment: Let me know how you misinterpreted the question, and I will try to edit it accordingly.

Comment: Be my guest. Look at my post now. You have function and each call returns a different permutation. It works just like you wanted to, right? It doesn't work with `1e10`, but this is NOT what you wrote in question, right? :) Next time tell us WHY you need this (because it has to work with great numbers).

Comment: Noted - thanks for your input - I will edit accordingly

Comment: I found `iterpc` package, check this :)

Comment: I was hoping for something of this ilk, but it seems to be limited by a function called `gammafn` e.g. try `iterpc(1000, 1000, ordered = TRUE)` :( regardless, thanks for your reply - for smaller ranges this package will no doubt be useful! :)

Comment: @Mullefa, this is the author of `iterpc`. Actually it is safe to use `getnext` when `n=1000`, however, it is not safe to do `getall`. Thanks for bringing this out. I will make suitable warnings for large `n` in next update.